# django data base filter by method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model with a method determines if I need to use it or not. I want to filter the table by the value returned from this method. something like this:

```
filter(object.method())
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: You can not filter by method. Since the database does not know anything about methods. Methods only exist at the Django/Python level, whereas `MyModel.objects.filter()` filters at the *database* level.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok, thanks.

Comment: As Willem pointed out, you cannot use methods in queryset filters. You can, however use [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/). You should check them out to see if they fit your use case.